# AngularJS and Typescript: Is explicit controller registration necessary?

Tags: angularjs, controller, typescript

In AngularJS you register a controller like this in the AngularJS main module to keep it out of global scope:

> We create an AngularJS Module, myApp, for our application. Then we add
>   the controller's constructor function to the module using the
>   .controller() method. This keeps the controller's constructor function
>   out of the global scope.
>   (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

```
app.controller("MyController", MyController);
```

Do you still need this registration when you use TypeScript Modules?

File1.ts:

```
module MyAngularApp {
    "use strict";
    export var app = angular.module("MyAngularApp", []);
}
```

File2.ts

```
module MyAngularApp {
    "use strict";

    export class MyController {
        constructor($scope) {
            $scope.models = {};
            $scope.models.helloAngular = "Hello Angular!";
        }
    }

    // Not Needed because of TypeScript Module?
    // MyAngularApp.app.controller("MyController", MyController);
}
```

HTML File:

```
<html ng-app="MyAngularApp" ng-controller="MyAngularApp.MyController">
<head>
    <title ng-bind="models.helloAngular"></title>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" ng-model="models.helloAngular" />
    <h1>{{models.helloAngular}}</h1>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/File1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/File2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code works without registering the controller in the module and I did not pollute the global scope.

Why should I register the controller in the AngularJS main module? Is there another benefit from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This code works without registering the controller in the Module and I did not pollute the global scope.

No it doesn't. You either have `MyController` in the global scope `window` OR you have it registered somewhere with `app.controller('MyController')`.

**Updated** Based on the update :

Since you are using `ng-controller="MyAngularApp.MyController` Angular is going to look on `MyAngularApp.MyController` in the global scope, where it does exist since that is where the internal modules go. This is different from `app.controller("MyController", MyController);` and is actually not required since you aren't using `ng-controller="MyController"`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am not sure if that is quite right. I updated the Code (forgot one export keyword) and I added the HTML Example. If you check the typeScript generated js Code, the MyController function is added to the MyAngularApp Object and not to the global scope.

Comment: @Daniel see update. Hope that clarifies any confusion

Comment: Thanks for your update and your answer. So I understand in that case the registration is not needed and doesn't bring any other advantages.